# Joomla Client sends multiple requests to controller

Tags: joomla, joomla3.7

I am using Joomla version 3.7.4
I have a form which sends a post request to a method called VerifyMe() in the controller. The form is like so:

```
<form action="myUrl" class="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="verifyUser"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="method" value="<?php echo 'type' ?>"/>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default bold uppercase"><?php echo JText::_('SEND') ?></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And in my controller, I have the method

```
 public function verifyMe()
    {
        JLog::add('VerifyMe Function called for '. $this->input->get('ID') , JLog::INFO, 'VerifyMe');

}
```

Now in the live environment, for some reason when the client clicks the submit button, the VerifyMe() function is called multiple times. This is not always the case but around 30% of the times its 2 or more calls for the same user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found the remedy.

Believe it or not, the solution is, tell the users not to "double-click" the buttons. Users tend to click web page buttons like they do to Windows icons.

If you really want to get rid of such problem, do some JavaScript to the template to disable the submit button on submit event.

Hope this helps.